Scary movie, characters get stabbed at the end?
I saw this movie some years back, new at the time, so probably around 2008.
At the end of the movie I found it very strange. Instead of something happening to save the main characters at the last minute, they end up getting stabbed slowly in the stomach on a couch. I remember thinking it was strange that the movie had such an "unhappy" ending.

I remembered the name, it is The Strangers (2008).

A young couple staying in an isolated vacation home are terrorized by three
  unknown assailants.

